# Program to write “math” logic for code semantics

Tags: linux, java, code-analysis

## Tldr;

Allows the user to define valid program state, valid program interactions, and then looks for sequences of interactions that would violate the valid program state.

#### Requirements

1. Runs on linux
2. Any language
3. Allows for multiple specified programs to interact with each other
4. Preferrably free

## Story

I am looking for **any** program that meets the requirements, and I know for a fact that such a program exists (my issue is not being able to find it)

I was watching a conference talk on YouTube about code testing and "logical" code testing for complicated interconnected systems (logical means that you could test your code against logical errors made by the programmer, aka doing action x then y then z will make your program's state not compliant to the mathematical rules that you have specified). The video had a very small amount of views <2k and it was at least 30 minutes long.

In that video the speaker (male) presented a program written in java that is free of charge in which you could specify valid states for interconnected systems with semi-math logic and the program would brute force all possible interactions to try to find a sequence of interactions where the program state which doesn't fit into the rules you specified.

I couldn't find the program or the video after a couple of days of trying different combinations of keywords on google, hence why I am asking this question.